# "Of a trilogy" vs. "in a trilogy"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

I've Googled for a while now, and can't seem to find any good answers to this.

Which of the following is correct?

> 1. X is the second installment in a trilogy.
> 2. X is the second installment of a trilogy.

Answer (score 3):

You should say:

> XXX is the second installment in a trilogy of books.

Because XXX belongs to the trilogy and is in it.

On the other hand, you'd say *of a trilogy* if speaking of the trilogy as a whole, like this:

> XXX marks the end of a trilogy.

Answer (score 2):

They are both correct English. If you're speaking of the position of something in a sequence you use "of". For example,

> The second of the three big snowstorms we had last year.

This usage can be extended to saying a book is the "second of a trilogy".

On the other hand, to say that a book is one of the members of a trilogy, you would say that it is "in the trilogy":

> There are five books in the *Hitchhiker's Guide* "trilogy".

(You can't use "of" here.) So saying "second in a trilogy" is also correct.

This Google Ngram shows they are both used.

[image]

Comment: As a native American English speaker, "of a trilogy" and "in a trilogy" sound essentially interchangeable to me.

*(Nice ngram, by the way!)*